# How to properly manage a dynamic table of data for gui

Tags: wpf, gridview, datatable, hierarchical-data, caliburn.micro

So I need to display a DataGrid in WPF. I'm using RadGridView from Telerik and Caliburn.Micro framework using the MVVM strategy.

In my presentation there are differing number of columns, X+2 to be exact as there is always a Label column and a Total column and then X number of others that hold a decimal number.

I do know the number at runtime before I create the classes I need so that could help.

So I'm currently considering a few methods of doing this but some of them have drawbacks so I would love if someone could point me towards a solution.

1. Create a ViewModel class for each row and for each Cell. The X number will be a collection and binding to it is problematic. I would need to customize the RadGridView itsefl to actually manage this.
2. Create a DataTable an the run and bind to it. I haven't managed to make this work and not sure if RadGridView actually supports DataTable. This will also not allow me to keep metadata for each cell, something I need to be easily able to update the cells because column + row aren't the only distinguishing keys I need.
3. Somehow dynamically create a object with x+2 properties to bind to.

Are there any solutions, guides or something out there to help me here?